# How do I place legend keys above bars/next to lines in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to follow best practices in plotting graphics using Tikz (see here http://www.eugenewei.com/blog/2017/11/13/remove-the-legend).

I'd like to 'remove the legend to become one': instead of placing legend keys in a small box below using the \legend command, I'd like to have them placed nicely above the individual bars/next to the lines in a line graph.

Is there any elegant way to do so/a kludge that works?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but please provide us with a code first.

Comment: For bar charts, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166930/add-label-to-bars-in-bar-chart (for example).  For graphs, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266849/how-to-label-maximum-y-coordinate-of-data-from-a-file-pgfplots?s=4|44.5640 (for example).  There may be better examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bar charts can be done, as pointed out by John Kormylo and as is illustrated in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166948/121799), by using `nodes near coords`. The lines are arguably even simpler: you only have to append the plot by `node[right] {...}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:5,clip=false,axis lines=left,trig format=rad]
  \addplot[blue] {x} node[right]{$x$};
  \addplot[red] {cos(x)} node[right]{$\cos(x)$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]