# Placing Legend Within Function Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot three figures using pgf/tikz, and want to have the following effect:[image: plots with the legend written inside them]

In other words, rather than having the legend separately, I want to [remove the legend to become one](https://www.eugenewei.com/blog/2017/11/13/remove-the-legend). In my particular plot (the image is a stylized example) writing the legend next/above the lines is not elegant, so I thought of writing them within the plots themselves.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my previously asked question here:

[How do I place legend keys above bars/next to lines in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458664/how-do-i-place-legend-keys-above-bars-next-to-lines-in-tikz)

already answers this perfectly. Just adding yshift and xshift will make things work.